# Initializing array of parameterized type in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11, valgrind

I'm working on a generic type in which i need an stack allocated array of the parameter type. It is supposed to be with as little overhead as possible. It was part of an exam, but now it has sparked my curiosity. I try looking around, but i failed to find anything useful.

I'm trying to create an array and initialize the members, but i'm not entirely sure how to do it properly. I have the following code:

```
T b[_dim]; // typeof(_dim) == size_t
```

Now T can be anything which have standard arithmetic operators, a default constructor. 
When T was a double i initialized the array with:

```
memset(b, 0, _dim*sizeof(T));
```

Which works fine for types such as doubles. Now the problem is that T could be a rational such as:

**Approach 1**

```
struct Rational
{
   int numerator;  
   int denominator;
   Rational(): numerator(0), denominator(1) {}
};
```

Which could cause trouble if we converted it to a double after everything has been set to 0.
Another approach is to run trough all the elements like this:

**Approach 2**

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < _dim; i++)
{
    b[i] = T();
}
```

What is an effecient way of initializing the members properly?

A side node is that when i do neither for another type than the rational. A double for instance. The program runs fine, but [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) complains with the following error messages (a lot of them, repeatedly):

```
==24450== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==24450==    at 0x5878B60: __printf_fp (printf_fp.c:731)
==24450==    by 0x5876B4B: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1654)
==24450==    by 0x589B654: vsnprintf (vsnprintf.c:119)
==24450==    by 0x53938FD: std::__convert_from_v(__locale_struct* const&, char*, int, char const*, ...) (c++locale.h:93)
==24450==    by 0x53A118C: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_float<double>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, char, double) const (locale_facets.tcc:997)
==24450==    by 0x53A141F: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, double) const (locale_facets.tcc:1144)
==24450==    by 0x53A5966: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<double>(double) (locale_facets.h:2398)
==24450==    by 0x433E9D: void boost::io::detail::put_last<char, std::char_traits<char>, double>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, double&) (feed_args.hpp:115)
==24450==    by 0x43273E: void boost::io::detail::put<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, double&>(double&, boost::io::detail::format_item<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::basic_format<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::string_type&, boost::basic_format<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::internal_streambuf_t&, std::locale*) (feed_args.hpp:176)
==24450==    by 0x43141F: void boost::io::detail::distribute<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, double&>(boost::basic_format<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, double&) (feed_args.hpp:253)
==24450==    by 0x42F22F: boost::basic_format<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >& boost::io::detail::feed<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, double&>(boost::basic_format<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, double&) (feed_args.hpp:263)
==24450==    by 0x42DB1E: boost::basic_format<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >& boost::basic_format<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator%<double>(double&) (format_class.hpp:68)
==24450== 
==24450== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==24450==    at 0x5878B6A: __printf_fp (printf_fp.c:731)
==24450==    by 0x5876B4B: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1654)
==24450==    by 0x589B654: vsnprintf (vsnprintf.c:119)
==24450==    by 0x53938FD: std::__convert_from_v(__locale_struct* const&, char*, int, char const*, ...) (c++locale.h:93)
==24450==    by 0x53A118C: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_float<double>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, char, double) const (locale_facets.tcc:997)
==24450==    by 0x53A141F: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, double) const (locale_facets.tcc:1144)
==24450==    by 0x53A5966: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<double>(double) (locale_facets.h:2398)
==24450==    by 0x433E9D: void boost::io::detail::put_last<char, std::char_traits<char>, double>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, double&) (feed_args.hpp:115)
==24450==    by 0x43273E: void boost::io::detail::put<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, double&>(double&, boost::io::detail::format_item<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::basic_format<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::string_type&, boost::basic_format<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::internal_streambuf_t&, std::locale*) (feed_args.hpp:176)
==24450==    by 0x43141F: void boost::io::detail::distribute<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, double&>(boost::basic_format<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, double&) (feed_args.hpp:253)
==24450==    by 0x42F22F: boost::basic_format<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >& boost::io::detail::feed<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, double&>(boost::basic_format<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, double&) (feed_args.hpp:263)
==24450==    by 0x42DB1E: boost::basic_format<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >& boost::basic_format<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator%<double>(double&) (format_class.hpp:68)
```

Doing either of my two approaches made valgrind stop complaining.

**Update** the variable _dim is indeed variable and is parsed in. g++11 says:

```
error: variable-sized object ‘b’ may not be initialized
```

**Solution and summary**
As pointed out, this call the ctor for all elements:

```
b T[_dim];
```

And as _dim is variable this does not work:

```
b T[_dim] = {};
```

But we can use do this::

```
T b[_dim];
if(std::is_fundamental<T>::value)
{
    memset(b, 0, _dim*sizeof(T));
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Array elements are default-initialized when you define the array.

Comment: @sftrabbit: But for non-class types, that is a no-initialization, isn't it?

Comment: @AndyProwl Yep, so maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. :D Edit: Ah, I get it now.

Comment: Great answers :) So with non inbuilt types it works fine without any extra initialization and with built-in types we need to use memcpy. 
And as @Jesse Good mentions we can use this: T b[_dim] = {}; Edit: But  this does not work for my array as it is of variable size (g++11 tells me that). Any clues how to check if inbuilt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [stfrabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470671/initialising-array-members-in-large-arrays-in-c#comment23632148_16470671) already points out, the default ctor will be called for you when you define the array. For the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Rational
{
   int numerator;  
   int denominator;
   Rational(): numerator(0), denominator(1)
   {std::cout << "Rational ctor!" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    Rational arr[10];
}
```

The output is:

```
Rational ctor!
Rational ctor!
Rational ctor!
Rational ctor!
Rational ctor!
Rational ctor!
Rational ctor!
Rational ctor!
Rational ctor!
Rational ctor!
```

So there is nothing special you have to do for class types. However, for built-in types there is no default ctor, so you need to add a couple of braces, i.e. `T b[_dim] = {};` to value initialize each element. By doing this it will work with class types and built-in types.

Comment: I think the OP just want the array to be initialized all the time, which means default-constructed when it contains class types, and value-initialized when it contains scalar types: "I'm working on a generic type in which i need an stack allocated array of the parameter type". Not sure if I haven't misunderstood the whole thing though

Comment: @AndyProwl: Yeah, you're probably right. I assumed the OP had a misunderstanding and wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can define override functions to initialize for different T, I assume the c++ you are using support override.

```
void init(double& t)
{
  t = 0;
}
void init(Rational& t)
{
   t.numerator = 0;
   t.denominator= 0;
}
```

and then:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < _dim; i++)
{
    inti(b[i]);
}
```